# nested linked list manipulation

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a list, each item in the list is also a list

All of sub-list has 2 elements, and they are linked together,

```
[l1, l2, l3, l4...]
```

the way they link together is `l2[-1]` equals to `l1[0]`, `l3[-1]` equals to `l2[0]`, `l4[-1]=l3[0]` and so on.

all of the sub-list has string element either like `'1 2 3'`(which is multiple unique numbers separated by whitespace) or `'7'`(only one number).

I want to make a transform of the below list

```
[['1 2 3', '4 5'], ['6 7', '1 2 3'], ['10', '6 7']]
```

the output would be

```
[[['1', '4'], ['6', '1'], ['10', '6']],
 [['2', '4'], ['6', '2'], ['10', '6']],
 [['3', '4'], ['6', '3'], ['10', '6']],
 [['1', '5'], ['6', '1'], ['10', '6']],
 [['2', '5'], ['6', '2'], ['10', '6']],
 [['3', '5'], ['6', '3'], ['10', '6']],
 [['1', '4'], ['7', '1'], ['10', '7']],
 [['2', '4'], ['7', '2'], ['10', '7']],
 [['3', '4'], ['7', '3'], ['10', '7']],
 [['1', '5'], ['7', '1'], ['10', '7']],
 [['2', '5'], ['7', '2'], ['10', '7']],
 [['3', '5'], ['7', '3'], ['10', '7']]]
```

where

- the element of the most inner list is a  string that contains only one number.
- the sublist also satisfies the property stated before.

---

I have a clue that it's like you have to pass every spot(six spots in the example) and pick out a number, which number to pick out depends on the pair you choose before, I haven't made more progress so far.

Comment: Note that this is something different from the commonly accepted definition of "[linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to generate all combinations and then pick out the "valid" ones, you can first get just the unique values from the list.
You can then get the `itertools.product` of those (after splitting the strings) and reconstruct the "linked" list from those:

```
lst = [['1 2 3', '4 5'], ['6 7', '1 2 3'], ['10', '6 7']]
sub = [lst[0][1]] + [x[0] for x in lst] # ['4 5', '1 2 3', '6 7', '10']
res =  [ [(b,a) for a,b in zip(p, p[1:])] for p in product(*map(str.split, sub))]
```

I'm using tuples instead of nested lists here just for readability of the complex list comprehension, feel free to replace the `(...)` with more `[...]`. Result:

```
[[('1', '4'), ('6', '1'), ('10', '6')],
 [('1', '4'), ('7', '1'), ('10', '7')],
 [('2', '4'), ('6', '2'), ('10', '6')],
 [('2', '4'), ('7', '2'), ('10', '7')],
 [('3', '4'), ('6', '3'), ('10', '6')],
 [('3', '4'), ('7', '3'), ('10', '7')],
 [('1', '5'), ('6', '1'), ('10', '6')],
 [('1', '5'), ('7', '1'), ('10', '7')],
 [('2', '5'), ('6', '2'), ('10', '6')],
 [('2', '5'), ('7', '2'), ('10', '7')],
 [('3', '5'), ('6', '3'), ('10', '6')],
 [('3', '5'), ('7', '3'), ('10', '7')]]
```

Comment: It's such an extraordinary insight!

Answer (score 1):

```
import copy

lst = [['1 2 3', '4 5'], ['6 7', '1 2 3'], ['10', '6 7']]

def print_list(ls):
    if ls is not None:
        for x in ls:
            print x

def transform_list(l):

    if(len(l)==0):
        print 'list provided is empty'
        return None

    tr=[] # intermediate transformed list

    for b in l[0][-1].split(' '):

        for a in l[0][0].split(' '):

            tr = tr + [[[a,b]]]

    for i in range(1,len(l)):
    
        new_tr = []
        
        for a in l[i][0].split(' '):
            
            temp_tr=copy.deepcopy(tr)

            for t in range(len(temp_tr)):

                temp_tr[t].append( [a,temp_tr[t][-1][0]] )

            new_tr = new_tr + temp_tr

        tr=copy.deepcopy(new_tr)
            
    return tr


print '\n\nOutput:'
transformed_list = transform_list(lst)
print_list(transformed_list)
```